# Is there a web site indexing cooking competitions, or an effective aggregator?

Tags: websites

Most sites that list cooking competitions are unfortunately holed up in one groups' pages and not easily searched.

I am looking for a site that indexes cooking competitions across various formats (i.e. chili, bbq, chowder, *whatever*), can provide event information, filter geographically and by event type.

A great site would index the events themselves as its sole function, but might also provide guidance/community elements.

What sites are currently out there that fit this bill?

Comment: I don't know about that specifically (the event-based such), but there's a "Google Recipe Search" : http://www.google.com/landing/recipes/

Comment: @Joe on googling I have only found [listings for either specific types](http://chilicookoff.com/), or [calendars that are not organized into a searchable index](http://www.contestcook.com/). This question is focused particularly on competitive cooking sites though, not sites for recipes.

Comment: I was going through old question and saw this one -- There seems to be one now (http://www.contestcook.com/), but I'm getting 'missing plugin' all of the place, so I don't know if they actually have anything.  Their facebook page seems to have recent posts, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site that has the best information I've found in regards to competitive cooking is [Contest Cook](http://www.contestcook.com/).  They don't quite meet all your criteria in terms of searchability, but they do some levels of sorting and provide a wealth of information on the contests they list (which are quite numerous).

Comment: That's actually the site that spurred the question

Comment: ah, sure - I didn't notice that it was in your comment up there.

Comment: The ironic thing about that site is they are leveraging both Google Ads and a custom Google site search, yet have not organized their own site to be easily searched in the way mfg (and I would bet others...) would like.

Answer (score 0):

The art of SEO (search engine optimization) is somewhere between elusive and completely ignored by a good number of people out there building websites. As a result even the best search engines often can not aggregate all of the "cooking competitions" in Columbus any more than they could find all the heavy metal being played in Cleveland on any given weekend.

So, I am afraid the short answer to your question is "No, There isn't".

The 'trick' is to find a way to get all of the hosts of cooking competitions to be willing to go to one place and list their competition. You have no doubt heard of Craig's List and Angie's List, well you can start mfg's list and see if you can't get some traction. Maybe Kraft or Ben E Keith will sponsor you? It is a good idea, but somebody has to make it happen.